# how to Rotate image one side using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsap

I am trying to rotate a image only one corner.image is like a pole .bottom side should not be changed the position only top of the image should be animate either clockwise or anti clockwise.i have tried like this.i should work in IE8 also.i made `left:53px` because bottom should not be change the position.

```
<style>
    .big-pole{
      background-image: url("images/pole.png");
      width: 55px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 78px;
      left: 53px;
    }
</style>
<script>
     TweenMax.to(".big-pole",3,{
        top:'100px',
        left:'53px',
       });

</script>
```

Comment: So you're trying to horizontally *flip* the image -- not "rotate"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: +1 for Greensock. Did you take the time to fully check their documentation. You are missing some parameters

Comment: like clock seconds hand the bottom part will be center top of the hand rotates.like that i am trying to do.

Comment: If it's a clock you're after, you might want to follow the tutorial for this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Clock/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand correctly what kind of rotation you are looking for? Is it like a clock as other users pointed out? Anyway your TweenMax call was missing some parameters in order for the rotation to work.

```
TweenMax.to($(".big-pole"), 3, {rotation:-90, transformOrigin:"top center"});
```

You will have test a few things and change a few value to find the correct animation, cause I might be wrong a bit, all depending on what you want to do in the end.

Comment: Oh bummer. Didn't read that part:: "It can't work miracles or, for example, permit fancy 3D transforms in IE8"... Let me check what I can do!

Comment: Hmm, is there a really good reason why you want to support IE8?

Comment: I don't know if you have a real version of IE 8 for you to see the real result, because I don't think IE11 in emulation mode can really show that

Comment: I found this plugin you could try, but i'm not sure what will be the results: [jquery.transform.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js)

Comment: Other than that, Greensock forum said to make sure your rotating element has an absolute position and be wrapped in a relative position container. For it to work, kind-of, in IE8 of course

Comment: But if you want my opinion, trying to bust your butt in order to support a dying browser which most people are using less and less (3.68% as of june 2014), is pretty useless and time consuming. If you have the tools to emulate IE8 correctly perfectly, you can try, but other than that, it's pointless

Comment: FYI, [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) does a fairly good job with emulating IE8, you can sign up for a free trial, but after that you must pay monthly fees to continue using the service

Answer (score 3):

You could apply CSS class to image without any need of external libraries.

```
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1); /* IE 8*/
}
```

Comment: i want support it to IE8 also. That's why i am trying to do with Jquery and Tweenmax.